# "Offline" Revocable Encryption, or something similar to it?

Tags: encryption

For context, I want to see how far I can go using YouTube as a (bad) cloud storage solution just because of sheer curiosity and kicks and giggles. In said journey, I came across the problem of properly encrypting the files I upload to YouTube. In a perfect world, I would like to allow for file sharing as close as I can to the cloud eliets like Google Drive. This means integrating features like the ability to "securely" share the file with others, the ability to revoke access, and the ability to change ownership of the file. However, this all has to be done in the confines of YouTube, which means that I can't re-encrypt the file without completely reuploading it (which eats away at YouTube's daily upload limit). I also can't utilize something like a server to gatekeep file access for me-- all of this would need to be dealt with as locally as possible.

As such, I'm pretty sure something like this is neigh impossible. So instead, what type of encryption could I use to accomplish something similar to this? Note that, while I would like to keep reuploading to a minimum, I can still utilize anything else YouTube can do (like changing the description, making playlists, and the like).

Comment: To begin with, are you sure their terms of service allow you to do what you describe?

Comment: This is just something I want to do for fun, so I won't upload the code to GitHub or something like that. Also, I'll be using Selenium instead of the YouTube API to do this (mostly because of the 5-video upload limit), and after a quick skim the YouTube guidelines, it doesn't seem to outright ban me from doing this either

Comment: I think it's impossible. However, you could use the description or comments to store master keys encrypted with user keys. If a user hadn't already retrieved their key and you deleted it from the description, they couldn't get it. If they already knew the file's master key, they could still download the file, but they could also have downloaded it before you removed their user key.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea! I'll try that and get back to you on how it goes. I was about to give up on this part of the project entirely due to the question getting closed. Because of this, I just kinda assumed that no one would help me. So thanks for chipping in :)